# xquery escape a bracket

Tags: file-io, networking, xquery

how do i grab a file accross the network with brackets in the name?
i.e.

fn:doc("file:////machine/folder/folder2/fi[le]1.xml")

fn:encode-for-uri() tries to grab locally

escape-uri function is not an option because its been dropped.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok to prevent from grabbing locally do this

```
fn:doc(concat("file:/",fn:encode-for-uri("//machine/folder/fi[le]1.xml")));
```

this prevents from going automatically local